# Add webpack to existing ruby project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack

I'm trying to add webpack to existing ruby project.

I try as said in [this doc](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#installation).

But when I run this command `gem 'webpacker', '~> 3.2'`

I have this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command webpacker,
```

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have node running on your machine ? From your terminal, try `node -v`

Ensure first you've added `gem 'webpacker'` in your Gemfile, and that you've ran `bundle install`after that

Then try the following : 
`bundle exec rake webpacker:install`

As an extra; it could be advised to run webpacker along your rails process. To do so, install foreman on your machine (`gem install foreman`), then create a Procfile at the root of your project, containing :

```
web: bin/rails server
assets: bin/webpack-dev-server
```

You then use `foreman start` instead of `rails s` to start your app

Comment: Got this
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'webpacker:install' (see --tasks)
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: see the edit, double check your gemfile and your nodejs install

Comment: Yeah. trouble was in gemfile. Thank's

Comment: you're welcome; do check this procfile setup, you'll be better off (:. and please accept thsi answer if it helped! best

Comment: Worth noting that you don't need foreman to do this. But it is handy.

Comment: Foreman is extra indeed